# Whenever I add a face then the whole square becomes black

Tags: uv, faces, uv-image-editor

[image]

Whenever I add a face then the whole square becomes black.
I already UV the square so that the face matches it, so I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand, could you please precisely describe the steps?

Comment: See if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=622uGwLxbPY) quick tutorial helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, maybe connect the alpha from the image to the Principled BSDF alpha?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

add rgb node to add color and add mixrgb to mix both image texture and rgb and plug them just like in photo